# Why is $\forall x \in \mathbb{N}\ \Phi(x,x)$ unary but $\Phi$ is binary?

Tags: computability

May anyone explain me why $\forall x \in \mathbb{N}\ \Phi(x,x)$ is unary but $\Phi$ is binary?

In my latest exam I wrote that the universal function $\Phi^n(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n,y) = \psi^n_y(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ is unary because its $n+1$ parameter is a constant referring to the number of the S-program ($y$), but my teacher corrected me writing: "Pay attention: $\Phi$ is binary (and its second parameter is not a constant), but $\Phi(x,x)$ is."

Comment: What does that even mean? Please explain your question clearly

Comment: One obvious moment, that possibly we can understand here is that, for example, $\Phi$ is defined on some $A \times B$ as some $\Phi(x,y)$ relation i.e. dependent on $2$ variables. And then, from it, we can derive $\Phi(x,x)$ as dependent on only $1$ variable. But may be OP means something different?

Comment: I have just edited my question. Check it out

Comment: The expression $\forall x \in \mathbb N \, \Phi(x,x)$ has no free variables, and so it is nullary.

Comment: Why not ask you teacher directly what he/she mean? One variant I suggested above - on second place you have same as on first($x$), so it is not parameter. It is variable, but same as on first place. Formally you take composition of $\Phi$ and diagonal.

Comment: I can't ask her right now

Comment: I have just edited my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of confusion arises because the sloppy notation and imprecise terminology involving free and bound variables. Let me try to clear some of it up.

The title of your question wrongly claims that $\forall x \in \mathbb{N} \,.\, \Phi(x,x)$ is a function, which it is not. It is a truth value. Let us see why this is the case.

Suppose someone defined $f$ by writing down
$$f(x,y) = x^2 + 3 y,$$
where $x$ and $y$ range over $\mathbb{N}$. First of all, it would be more precise to define $f$ like this:
$$f = ((x, y) \mapsto x^2 + 3 y).$$
The right-hand side is read as "the *function* which maps $(x,y)$ to $x^2 + 3 y$". The variables $x$ and $y$ are *bound*, i.e., we get *the same function* if we rename them, for example $(u, v) \mapsto u^2 + 3 v$ is equal to $f$.
The function $f$ is *binary* because it takes two arguments.

With $f$ defined as above:

1. The expression $f(x, y)$ is *not a function*! It is a number. Indeed, you would have no trouble claiming that $f(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}$, would you? However, this number is *parameterized* by two *free variables* $x$ and $y$. Thus, *which* number it is *depends* on $x$ and $y$.
2. The previous remark maybe becomes clearer if we contemplate the fact that $f(3, 4)$ is not a function but a number, and so is $f(u,u)$ where $u \in \mathbb{N}$ is a free variable.
3. We can fix just one of the arguments to get a unary function, for example $x \mapsto f(x, 7)$ is unary because it is a map $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.
4. The expression $f(x, 7)$ is not a function! It is a number, parameterized by the free variable $x$.

Next, consider the definition
$$g = (x \mapsto x^2 + 3 y).$$
The function $g$ is *unary* because it takes one argument. However, $g$ *depends* on the free variable $y$. (Some people may call this $y$ a "constant", or call $x$ an "argument" and $y$ a "parameter", but let us not do that. We will stick strictly to the terminology "$x$ is a bound variable" and "$y$ is a free variable".) We may rename the bound variable but not the free one:

- $(u \mapsto u^2 + 3 y)$ is equal to $g$
- $(u \mapsto u^2 + 3 v)$ is *not* equal to $g$ because $y$ and $v$ are different free variables
- $(y \mapsto y^2 + 3 y)$ is not equal to $g$ because the free variable $y$ does *not* appear in it.

Some people might define $g$ above like this:
$$g_y = (x \mapsto x^2 + 3 y).$$
They want to indicate that $y$ is a free variable in the definition of $g$. In our notation, this would correspond to
$$g = (y \mapsto (x \mapsto x^2 + 3 y))$$
so that now $g$ is a *unary* function *without* free variables. When we apply $g$ to $y$ by writing $g_y$, we again get a unary function, this time wit one free variable $y$. By the way, writing $g_y$ instead of $g(y)$ is just cosmetics.

Consider
$$\Phi = ((u, v) \mapsto u < 7 \lor (v + u^2 > 6).$$
Then $\Phi$ is a *binary function* because it maps from $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ to $\{\bot, \top\}$. It should be clear that:

- $\Phi(x,x)$ is *not a function*. It is a truth value parametrized by the free variable $x$.
- $x \mapsto \Phi(x,x)$ is a *unary function* mapping from $\mathbb{N}$ to truth values $\{\bot, \top\}$.
- $\forall x \in \mathbb{N} \,.\, \Phi(x,x)$ is *not* a function. It is a truth value. Indeed, we can plug in $\Phi$ and get $\forall x \in \mathbb{N} \,.\, x < 7 \lor (x + x^2 > 6)$, which is false (a truth value, not a function).

What I think you really wanted to ask was this: why is $\Phi$ binary but $x \mapsto \Phi(x,x)$ is unary? Is the answer not obvious, once we use correct notation that does not mess up free and bound variables?

Regarding the discussion with your teacher, there you need to correctly indicate which things are supposed to be free variables and which ones arguments of functions. You wrote:
$$\Phi^n(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y) = \Psi_y^n(x_1, \ldots, x_n).$$
I am sure you can see such thigs in textbooks, but they are a bit sloppy. To be very precise, we need information on which things in $\Psi$ are supposed to be free variables and which ones are arguments. I would guess that what is meant is that
$$\Psi_y^n : \underbrace{\mathbb{N} \times \cdots \mathbb{N}}_n \to \mathbb{N},$$
which means that
$$\Psi : \mathbb{N} \to (\mathbb{N} \to \underbrace{\mathbb{N} \times \cdots \mathbb{N}}_n \to \mathbb{N})).$$
We see that $\Psi$ is a unary function, $\Psi_n$ is a unary function, and $\Psi^y_n$ is an $n$-ary function with free variables $n$ and $y$.
If we read your definition as
$$\Phi = (n \mapsto ((x_1, \ldots, x_n, y) \mapsto \Psi_y^n(x_1, \ldots, x_n)))$$
then $\Phi$ is an unary function and $\Phi_n$ is an $(n+1)$-ary function with free variable $n$.